# Remove a word and everything after

Tags: c#, string

Let's say I have a string:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe /lets go 342131 some random text"
```

And I want to remove from that string the 'steam.exe' and everything that follows after that. So my trimmed string would look like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\"
```

How can I do that in C#?

Comment: [String.IndexOf Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to remove something from the end of a  string use [`String.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int indexOfSteam = text.IndexOf("steam.exe");
if(indexOfSteam >= 0)
    text = text.Remove(indexOfSteam);
```

It's the same as `text.Substring(0, indexOfSteam)`. It just makes the intention clearer.

Answer (score 17):

Simply use `IndexOf` and `Substring` methods:

```
int index = str.IndexOf("steam.exe");  
string result = str.Substring(0, index);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.IO.Path`:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath)
```

which will return "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam"

Answer (score -3):

```
...
string str_ = "123\123"
string str_splitted = str_.split(@"\")[0];
...
```

EDIT: here is my explanation:

The split-Function for strings is in my opinion the simpliest solution to get to your wanted results. Because of the fact that you can specify a particular char to split your string at this position.

You always keep the full control of the process ;)

Comment: It's a sad reflection of the mentality of negative voters that an almost identical answer that Ehsan Sajjad gave (AFTER YOU POSTED THIS ANSWER) has 3 positive votes whilst yours had 4 negative votes.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitos, when you add some explaination.