# C# Automation Multiline String Trim

Tags: c#, string, winforms, edit, trim

I am wondering how I can trim every string of an array after a certain char, for example I have 1 textbox in which I put a multiline string like:

> HelloWorld:123
>
> IAmABerliner:JFK

and then I want to click a Button and in the second TextBox everything in every line should be trimmed after the ":"

Output in Textbox 2:

> HelloWorld
>
> IamABerliner

Comment: win forms, sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: I am new to this forum... doing my best :(

Comment: You should use [`string.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) and split on the newline character, then use it to split each line on the `:` character

Comment: Can you send me the code?

Comment: I think this will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661798/remove-a-word-and-everything-after

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use the `string.Split` method, and take just the first part of it:

```
string result = textBox2.Text.Split(':')[0];
```

For multiline strings:

```
string result = string.Empty;

foreach (string line in textBox2.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()))
{
    result += line.Split(':')[0] + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: This does not account for the lines/new line characters

Comment: Does Work* Sorry I am dumb ;D

Comment: Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the feedback. you are welcome to disagree. I prefer the simplicity of this over unecessary `Regex`, `Linq` and `for` loops...

Comment: lambda are simplified foreach loops, but i guess is ok for a beginner level answer, we don't want to confuse our new developer so soon !

Comment: @Mike lambdas are not simplified `foreach` loops. They require understanding about anonymous functions, deferred execution and scope capture. They are just more concise...

Comment: How is a foreach loop simpler than a for loop? Like lambdas they're more concise but for loops are one of the simplest things in programming.

Answer (score 4):

WinForms Texboxes have a [Lines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

You can iterate over those lines using Linq and split on `:`, then take the `First()` index

```
someTextBox.Lines = someTextBox.Lines.Select(x => x.Split(':').First()).ToArray();
```

Comment: you cant do s = in a foreach method

Comment: @EuropeanRiven Was in a call and not paying attention, check the update

Comment: easily the easiest to implement and understand solution

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative, and I'd really prefer the other methods, but you could also use regex:

```
txtInput.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(txtInput.Text, "(?m):.*$", string.Empty);
```

- `(?m)` turns on multiline mode
- `:` matches literal colon
- `.*` matches zero or more (`*`) of any character except newline (`.`)
- `$` matches the end of the line (but not the newline) due to multiline mode being enabled

Comment: easily the most efficient solution but hard to understand to most people without too much use or understanding of regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but this is what I came up with.

```
string input = TextBox1.Text;
string[] input_split = input.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string output = "";
for(int i = 0; i < input_split.Length; i++)
{
    string[] split_again = input_split[i].Split(':');
    output += split_again[0];
}
TextBox2.Text = output;
```

I tested it and it gave the desired output.

Comment: you just take the strings I gave as examples. But I want to take the multiline string from the windowsform TextBox.

Comment: Yes, I used them as an example, but the code below that will work for any multiline input in that format.

Comment: I edited it to make it more generic. You should be able to copy/paste that into your code and change the text box names and it'll work.

Comment: lambda > linq !

Answer (score 0):

You can use this little snippet to get the string you want:

```
string trimmedInput = string.Join(
    "\n", 
    input
       .Split('\n')
       .Select(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(":"))));
```

It firsts gets an array of all lines, then trims it after the semicolon and then puts them back together in one string rather an array of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Following simple Code using StringBuilder and split working for me.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var st = textBox1.Text.Split('\n');
for (int i = 0; i < st.Length; i++)
{
   sb.AppendLine(st[i].Split(':')[0]);
}
textBox2.Text = sb.ToString();
```